# Determine biggest height of total amount of <p>'s within <div>

Tags: jquery, css

I have X amount of divs. Each div have a different amount of `<p>`'s.

```
<div class="box">
    <p>paragraf 1</p>
    <ul class="note">
        <li>Note 1</li>
        <li>Note 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <p>paragraf 1</p>
    <p>paragraf 2</p>
    <ul class="note">
        <li>Note 1</li>
        <li>Note 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Im trying to iterate through each div and determine which div - based on the totalt amount of `<p>`'s within each `<div>` - have the total highest height.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cjq8h26c/

My use-case is ultimately to re-position my `<ul class="note">` in each div to vertically align from top based on the total highest `<p>` height.

I've managed to iterate through each div and found the height of each.

. **My issue is: Based on the `<p>` heights found, how do I determine which totalt height is biggest and save that number to a var?**

In the below case (based on the fiddle) the third div with 144+126 = 270 - would be the number im looking for.

```
[p, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: div.box, selector: "p", jquery: "2.1.3", constructor: function…]
        Height: 144
[p, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: div.box, selector: "p", jquery: "2.1.3", constructor: function…]
        Height: 180
[p, p, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: div.box, selector: "p", jquery: "2.1.3", constructor: function…]
        Height: 144
        Height: 126
```

Comment: I updated the fiddle in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add them up as you loop through them?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/69s4nyx1/2/)

```
if ($('.box').length){
    var highestpar = 0;
    $('.box').each(function(){
        pars = $(this).find("p");
        console.log(pars);
        var thispartot = 0;
        pars.each(function(){
            parHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
            thispartot = thispartot + parHeight;
            console.log(parHeight);
        });
        if (thispartot > highestpar) { highestpar = thispartot; }
        console.log('total: '+thispartot);
        console.log('highest: '+highestpar);
    })
    console.log('highestfinal: '+highestpar);
}
```